# Mysql, get rows before specific row in a multi-column index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

Say I have this table for high-scores:

```
id : primary key
username : string
score : int
```

User names and scores themselves can be repeating, only id is unique for each person. I also have an index to get high-scores fast:

```
UNIQUE scores ( score, username, id )
```

How can I get rows below the given person? By 'below' I mean they go before the given row in this index.

E.g. for ( 77, 'name7', 70 ) in format ( score, username, id ) I want to retrieve:

```
77, 'name7', 41
77, 'name5', 77
77, 'name5', 21
50, 'name9', 99
```

but not

```
77, 'name8', 88 or
77, 'name7', 82 or
80, 'name2', 34 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result:

```
SELECT t.score
     , t.username
     , t.id
  FROM scores t
 WHERE ( t.score < 77 ) 
    OR ( t.score = 77 AND t.username < 'name7' )
    OR ( t.score = 77 AND t.username = 'name7' AND t.id < 70 )
 ORDER
    BY t.score DESC
     , t.username DESC
     , t.id DESC
```

(NOTE: the ORDER BY clause may help MySQL decide to use the index to avoid a "`Using filesort`" operation. Your index is a "covering" index for the query, so we'd expect to see "`Using index`" in the `EXPLAIN` output.)

---

I ran a quick test, and in my environment, this does perform a range scan of the index and avoids a sort operation.

**EXPLAIN OUTPUT**

```
id  select_type table type  possible_keys      key        rows Extra                     
--  ----------- ----- ----- ------------------ ---------- ---- --------------------------
 1  SIMPLE      t     range PRIMARY,scores_UX1 scores_UX1    3 Using where; Using index
```

---

(You may want to add a `LIMIT n` to that query, if you don't need to return ALL the rows that satisfy the criteria.)

If you have an unique id of a row, you could avoid specifying the values in the table by doing a join. Given the data in your question:

Here we use a second reference to the same table, to get the row id=70, and then a join to get all the rows "lower".

```
SELECT t.score
     , t.username
     , t.id
  FROM scores k
  JOIN scores t
    ON ( t.score < k.score ) 
    OR ( t.score = k.score AND t.username < k.username )
    OR ( t.score = k.score AND t.username = k.username AND t.id < k.id )
 WHERE k.id = 70
 ORDER
    BY t.score DESC
     , t.username DESC
     , t.id DESC
 LIMIT 1000
```

The EXPLAIN for this query also shows MySQL using the covering index and avoiding a sort operation:

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys      key         rows Extra
-- ----------- ----- ----- ------------------ ----------  ---- ------------------------
 1 SIMPLE      k     const PRIMARY,scores_UX1 PRIMARY       1
 1 SIMPLE      t     range PRIMARY,scores_UX1 scores_UX1    3  Using where; Using index
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "below" for repeating scores is quite fuzzy: Think of 11 users having the same score, but you want the "10 below" a special row. That said, you can do something like (assuming you start with id=70)

```
SELECT score, username, id 
FROM scores
WHERE score<=(SELECT score FROM scores WHERE id=77)
ORDER BY if(id=77,0,1), score DESC
  -- you might also want e.g. username 
LIMIT 5 -- you might want such a thing
;
```

Which will give you the rows in question inside this fuzzy factor, with the anchor row first.

**Edit**

Re-reading your question, you don't want the anchor row, so you need `WHERE score<=(...) AND id<>77` and forget the first part of the `ORDER BY`

**Edit 2**

After your update to the question, I understand you want only those rows, that have one of

- score < score in anchor row
- score == score in anchor row AND name < name in anchor row
- score == score in anchor row AND name == name in anchor row AND id < id in anchor row

We just have to put that into a query (again assuming your anchor row has id=70):

```
SELECT score, username, id 
FROM scores, (
  SELECT 
    @ascore:=score, 
    @ausername:=username,
    @aid:=id
  FROM scores 
  WHERE id=70
) AS seed
WHERE
  score<@ascore
  OR (score=@ascore AND username<@ausername)
  OR (score=@ascore AND username=@ausername AND id<@aid)
ORDER BY
  score DESC,
  username DESC,
  id DESC
-- limit 5 //You might want that
;
```

Comment: Hi Eugen, your solution retrieves the same additional rows as Gordon's solution. I added examples of rows that are 'above' the base row. Btw, 'below'/'above' are not fuzzy when id is unique for each record. The index orders all records in a unique way - I just need the 'bottom' part of it...

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. Yes your solution works too. Basically the whole problem for me was how to put all those conditions into 1 select, I'm just starting with SQL...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you want:

```
select s.*
from scores s
where s.score <= (select score
                  from scores
                  where id = 70
                 ) and
      s.id <> 70
order by scores desc
limit 4;
```

Comment: Gordon, your solution will nearly make it, but it will also return all rows with equal score and name but larger id. And they are not 'below' my given row. It's like in a dictionary: if first and second symbols in words (e.g. ABC and ABB) are the same, then third symbol should be alphabetically 'smaller' in the second word for it to be 'below' the first word in a dictionary. Also, it's the same with multi-column indexes.